# Adding Hash to Array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, hash, ruby-on-rails-2

I have the following code which is taking results from an api call and providing it to my front-end as json:

```
notes = { :notes => [] }

json['Response']['OperationResponse']['Notes']['Note'].each do |note|
    notes[:notes] << [:user => note['User'], :time_stamp => note['TimeStamp'], :text => note['Text']]
end

render :json => notes.to_json
```

but I'm getting this format:

```
{
    "notes": [
        [
            {
                "time_stamp": "test",
                "user": "test",
                "text": "test"
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "time_stamp": "test",
                "user": "test",
                "text": "test"
            }
        ],
        ....
```

Instead of this desired format:

```
{
    "notes": [
        [
            {
                "time_stamp": "test",
                "user": "test",
                "text": "test"
            },

            {
                "time_stamp": "test",
                "user": "test",
                "text": "test"
            },
            ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with

```
json['Response']['OperationResponse']['Notes']['Note'].each do |note|
    notes[:notes] << {:user => note['User'], :time_stamp => note['TimeStamp'], :text => note['Text']}
end
```

You are pushing the element as an array `[]`, use `{}` instead.

Comment: ah, I thought it would be something I was missing but didn't think it'd be as simple as that! Thanks.

Comment: Glad to Help. Please accept the answer after time out is over. :)